# DITG and Mininet Disconnectivity Issues

Tags: networking, load-balancing, mininet, sdn, ryu

I want to set up a simulated network Kary-Fattree topology via mininet and test load balancing( one client sends to three server) using ryu as the controller and DITG as the traffic generator and monitor.

Now I've done most of the work, but when I try to establish a connection to DITG, I find that most of the time there is always a random DITG Server (IRecv) that can't be connected to (the disconnected ip addresses are different every time), like following flow chart shows(At this time, ip 10.0.0.1->10.0.0.3 was not established. When use ss command to access the network, I found the server 10.0.0.3 was not listening on the port assigned using ISend cmd):

```
 cookie=0x0, duration=1136.234s, table=0, n_packets=4, n_bytes=296, priority=3,tcp,nw_src=10.0.0.1,nw_dst=10.0.0.3 actions=group:75904
 cookie=0x0, duration=1136.234s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=3,tcp,nw_src=10.0.0.3,nw_dst=10.0.0.1 actions=output:"s1-eth1"
 cookie=0x0, duration=1136.234s, table=0, n_packets=180986, n_bytes=280392249, priority=3,tcp,nw_src=10.0.0.1,nw_dst=10.0.0.6 actions=group:75904
 cookie=0x0, duration=1136.234s, table=0, n_packets=91461, n_bytes=6039427, priority=3,tcp,nw_src=10.0.0.6,nw_dst=10.0.0.1 actions=output:"s1-eth1"
 cookie=0x0, duration=1136.234s, table=0, n_packets=5050, n_bytes=7960000, priority=3,tcp,nw_src=10.0.0.1,nw_dst=10.0.0.7 actions=group:75904
 cookie=0x0, duration=1136.234s, table=0, n_packets=2638, n_bytes=174187, priority=3,tcp,nw_src=10.0.0.7,nw_dst=10.0.0.1 actions=output:"s1-eth1"
 cookie=0x0, duration=926.119s, table=0, n_packets=27, n_bytes=1470, priority=1,in_port="s1-eth1",dl_src=00:00:00:00:00:01,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:03 actions=output:"s1-eth3"
 cookie=0x0, duration=915.471s, table=0, n_packets=27, n_bytes=1470, priority=1,in_port="s1-eth1",dl_src=00:00:00:00:00:01,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:06 actions=output:"s1-eth3"
 cookie=0x0, duration=906.113s, table=0, n_packets=33, n_bytes=1722, priority=1,in_port="s1-eth1",dl_src=00:00:00:00:00:01,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:07 actions=output:"s1-eth2"
 cookie=0x0, duration=848.474s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=1,in_port="s1-eth3",dl_src=00:00:00:00:00:06,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:01 actions=output:"s1-eth3"
 cookie=0x0, duration=618.703s, table=0, n_packets=12, n_bytes=616, priority=1,in_port="s1-eth2",dl_src=00:00:00:00:00:06,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:00:07 actions=output:"s1-eth3"
 cookie=0x0, duration=1138.379s, table=0, n_packets=723230, n_bytes=122047943, priority=0 actions=CONTROLLER:65535
```

and the rest of them can be connected to. This makes me confused. What could be the reason for this? How should I debug this?